# KB5004442 - Windows DCOM Server Security Feature Bypass (CVE-2021-26414) having issue

Tags: windows, wmi, rpc, windows-server-2019, dcom

After enabling the registry followed by the below doc. we are facing issues as access denied even after using `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY` on WMI.

> Windows Server 2019 Version 1809 (OS build 17763.2268). windows
> updated KB5006744

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c

Answer (score 0):

Important Notes (for environments where the hotfix is not installed):
The setting documented in KB5004442 **does not remove the alerts from the DC Server, but it does restore traffic flow**.If you do not enable the new setting documented in KB5004442 (while this is still possible), you can continue working with AD Query.This makes your Windows server vulnerable to CVE-2021-26414.

https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk176148